# How to control instance in another view controller

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6

I'm new to Swift and OS X programming.

I am creating a desktop application with two view controllers, which are in a split view controller. How can I get access to the instances in another controller and change its attributes?

An example:

We have a drawing application, one view is canvas, the other is tools. There is a 'clear' button in tool view, how to set the canvas clear when click on this button?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use singleton pattern in your code. When you create the view controller, put the var out of the class like:

```
var fooViewController = FooViewController(...)

class FooViewController{
...
}
```

Then you can use the fooViewController anywhere in your project.

If you are working with storyboard, you can try some code like this:

```
var story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
var view:MainTabViewController = story.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainTab") as MainTabViewController
```

Hope this can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegates and protocols! [Link to Official Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

Heres a quick example:

```
protocol toolsProtocol {
    func pressedClear()
}
var delegate : toolsProtocol
```

In your canvas class

```
class Canvas: UIViewController, toolsProtocol {
    Tools.delegate = self
    func pressedClear() {
       // Insert stuff happens here
    }
}
```